# Getting error while passing Class_weight parameter in Random Forest

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am doing binary classifier. Since my data is unbalanced  i am using class weight. I am getting error  while  passing values how to fix this.

**Error:    ValueError: class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None, got: [{0: 0.4, 1: 0.6}]"**

**Code**

```
rf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,oob_score=True,min_samples_leaf=500,class_weight=[{0:.4, 1:.6}])
    fit_rf=rf.fit(X_train_res,y_train_res)
```

**Error**

```
\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py in compute_class_weight(class_weight, classes, y)
     60         if not isinstance(class_weight, dict):
     61             raise ValueError("class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None,"
---> 62                              " got: %r" % class_weight)
     63         for c in class_weight:
     64             i = np.searchsorted(classes, c)

ValueError: class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None, got: [{0: 0.4, 1: 0.6}]
```

How to fix this.

Comment: Since you have only one dict for class weight, try to remove the bracket and just pass the dict.  `class_weight={0:0.4, 1:0.6}`.

Comment: @ScottBoston, Thanks it worked, Can you briefly explain how class weights  works. My objective  is basically reduce class 1 being misclassified  as class 0. My data is highly unbalanced with 80% from class 0 and 20% from class1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

> class_weight : dict, list of dicts, “balanced”,

Therefore, the class_weight paramter accepts a dictionary, a list of dictionary, or the string "balanced".  The error message you are given states that it wants a dictionary, and since you have only one dictionary a list is not needed.

So, let's try:

```
rf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,
                          oob_score=True,
                          min_samples_leaf=500,
                          class_weight={0:.4, 1:.6})

fit_rf=rf.fit(X_train_res,y_train_res)
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if you look for balanced weights (i.e. not all the labels come with the same stats) you can use this call to balance the weights

```
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
# y is your labels vector, one entry for each sample
classWeight = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(y), y=y)
# this is the dictionary you need to input as required by the syntax - see previous answer
classWeight = dict(zip(np.unique(y), classWeight.flatten()))
# now you can proceed as required - e.g.:
rf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,
                          oob_score=True,
                          min_samples_leaf=500,
                          class_weight=classWeight)
```